# App to manage copy and paste?

Tags: copy-paste

I'm looking for an app to manage copy and paste tasks.

What I need is to have shorcuts to the last copied text.

Let's say I copy these 4 lines in 4 times:

```
111111
222222
333333
444444
```

Then I'd like to have 4 shortcuts to paste every one of them. Something like:

cmd + 1 (to paste '111111')
cmd + 2 (to paste '222222')
and so on..

The closed match I found is [Clipmenu](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/29988/clipmenu) since it seems that you can use the shortcuts I need (cmd + 1, cmd + 2...) but it doesn't work though

Comment: Why doesn't Clipmenu work?

Comment: the shortcut simple doesn't work. If I copy some text and press cmd + 1 I just hear a sound and nothing happens. Should I set some actions in Preferences?

Comment: Please open another question for the Clipmenu issue then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [FlyCut](http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/flycut-clipboard-manager/id442160987?mt=12), you can do Cmd-Shift-V and then cycle through your recently copied texts with arrow keys.